# NSURLSession Initializer error

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to create an NSURLSession like so:

```
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate:self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

so I can do some downloading and such, but I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot find initializer for type 'NSURLSession' that accepts an argument list of type '(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration, delegate: AppDelegate, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue)'
```

I've check the documentation and there definitely is an initializer with those arguments. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `NSURLSessionDelegate` as a protocol to the class declaration.

```
class TheClassName: SuperClassName, NSURLSessionDelegate {
```

The error messages states:

Cannot find initializer for type 'NSURLSession' that accepts an argument list of type
'(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration, delegate: **AppDelegate**, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue)'

The documentation for the initializer:
init(configuration configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration, delegate delegate: **NSURLSessionDelegate**?, delegateQueue queue: NSOperationQueue?)

Take away: read the error messages *really* carefully.